# Will I encounter problems after applying interior paint over exterior?

Tags: paint

The usual story of grabbing the wrong thing off the shelf and only noticing after the work was done...

I'm not bothered by the short-term outgassing, but I'm concerned that exterior paint is often softer than interior, as it has to flex more in outdoor conditions.

I still have a coat to go on my skirting boards.

If I buy the equivalent latex paint in its interior form and use that for the final coat, will its strength be compromised by the softer first coat?  Would I be better off completing the work all with exterior paint?

Obviously the very best that I could do is sand it all down and start from scratch.  That's not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you'll encounter problems, but it depends on the specific products, of course. Exterior paint isn't exactly rubbery. I'd do it. If the manufacturer or retailer advise against it, use a sealing primer in between.

Answer (score 0):

Exterior paints are made to tolerate harsher weather condition as obvious our exterior surface is much more exposed to UV rays, rain, wind, heat, pollution and others.

Broadly, paint is comprised of four components: **Pigment**, **Binder**, **Solvent** and **Additives**. Exterior paints will have higher proportion of UV resistant pigment (one of the reasons why it costs higher) which are primarily inorganic leading to limited shades. Binders should be able to withstand mechanical shock and provide resistance to strong heat, wind and pollutants.

Finally, if you still plan to go with an interior paint over an exterior surface, you can get a more beautiful appearance but your repainting cycle would be shortened.